# Changing battery from 12v SLA to 12v Lithium, how can i accomplish this setup?

Tags: batteries, 12v, lithium

I am thinking of more speed for a kick scooter project.
I have a 800w hub motor for this scooter but at only 40Km/h i am thinking of making it go faster.
Now I know that increasing the voltage from 48 to 60v would do,
But what would happen by using a 1800w controller, would the increase wattage make it go faster?, is increased wattage going to make it faster?.

Here is controller and 800w hub.

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Regen-braking-BLDC-48V-1800W-18-mosfet-top-quality-sine-wave-controller-high-power-e-scooter/32607657598.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.128.F7JNr3&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_9,searchweb201602_1_10034_507_10032_10020_10017_10005_10006_10021_10022_10009_10008_10018_10019,searchweb201603_7&btsid=0bd124bf-0c76-4de8-be01-5960288c65d6

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/10-800W-48v-electric-motor-skateboard-electric-motor-scooter-electric-brushless-gearless-hub-motor/32649887917.html

Comment: The linked page says "Output current 1-2A" apparently referring to the battery. If it really means that, ... tough luck, you need over 20A to run the scooter at 1000W.

Comment: @BrianDrummond judging by the diameter of the wire I think it really does mean 1 to 2A.

Answer (score 2):

Can it work? No, sorry.

If your scooter has a 1000W motor then it will draw (take from the battery) 20 Amps. The spec for the Lithium batteries in the link lists the maximum output current as 1 to 2 Amp, which is nowhere near enough for your scooter. If you tried to use these lithium batteries then one of two things may happen:

1. the batteries may have a built in fuse which will 'blow' and stop the scooter working at all.
2. the batteries will attempt to deliver 20A, but rapidly overheat and fail. There is even a small chance that they may set on fire.

It is also worth noting that your SLA batteries have a capacity of 12Ah, whereas the lithium batteries have a capacity of 6.8Ah. Even if they did work they would give you about half the range of the SLA batteries.

These lithium batteries are only suitable for relatively low power and low current applications, such as powering electronic equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Specification from the eBay posting:

- Size:114x57x20mm(battery)
- Color: Blue
- Capacity: 6800mAh.
- Battery type: Rechargeable Li-on battery.
- Input voltage: 12.6V
- Output voltage: 10.8~12.6 DC
- **Output current: 1-2A**
- Line interface specification 5.5 * 2.1 MM
- Product life:    circulation charge and discharge more than 500 times

As you can see from the specifications each battery could supply **up to 2 A** giving 12 V x 2 A = 24 W. With all four you'll have 96 W available to drive your 1,000 W motor. These batteries are intended for low-power applications. They will not suit your bike.

Your original setup had 12 Ah batteries. These ones, even if they could supply the required current, are 6.8 Ah capacity. Available energy is half of the lead-acid batteries.

Comment: Where do you get 12x2=24V from?

Comment: Oops! 12 V x 2 A = 24 W. I must have been thinking vatts, eh? Fixed, thanks.